# How does a function detect string pointer vs string literal argument?

Tags: c++, string, detect, literals

I have encountered a function, such that it can differentiate between being called as

```
foo("bar");
```

vs

```
const char *bob = "bar";
foo(bob);
```

Possibilities I have thought of are:

- Address of string: both arguments sat in .rdata section of the image. If I do both calls in the same program, both calls receive the same string address.
- RTTI: no idea how RTTI can be used to detect such differences.

The only working example I could conjure up is:

```
void foo(char *msg)
{
    printf("string literal");
}

void foo(const char *&msg)
{
    printf("string pointer");
}

foo("bar");                 // "string literal"

const char *soap = "bar";
foo(soap);                  // "string pointer"
```

I do not have access to the function's code, and the declarations in the header file only revealed one function declaration.

Comment: And what was that function declaration?

Comment: How can you tell it's differentiating between those two call types?

Comment: I might have overlooked something. The code is at work so I'll get to it in a few hours :)

The function complains when we do not pass in string literals.

Comment: Funny: It actually seems to work. But it fails to compile for me as I always have warning treated as errors and because this generates a warning when compiled it fails. You are relying on a depricated feature that string literals (which are char const*) will decay to (char*) for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Martin York: deprecation doesn't mean anything in C++. It's defined in the standard as "not guaranteed to remain in future versions of the standard". But non-deprecated features aren't guaranteed to remain in future versions of the standard either (e.g. `export` is to be removed in C++0x without ever being deprecated). The string literal -> `char*` conversion is a bad idea because it's not const-safe, not because it's deprecated. There's no real risk of it suddenly vanishing and your program doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Steve: well, the literal to `char*` conversion *is* being removed in C++0x.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: But deprecated does mean the compiler will probably warn you about the situation.

Comment: @Martin: in this case it does. My compiler doesn't warn me for `#include <stdio.h>`, though (D.5), or `static int i;` in namespace scope (D.2), or incrementing a boolean (D.1), or an access declaration (D.3). This is `g++ -Wall -Wextra`. I'm not going through the whole chapter, but I again submit that this warning is not there because the conversion is deprecated, it's because it's dangerous.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Sure, but I'm not going to hold my breath waiting for a major C++0x compiler which lacks a C++03 mode. My point is (a) that deprecation means nothing in C++, and (b) that the reasons for not using that conversion have nothing to do with deprecation or future standards. In a faster-moving language or library, deprecation might be genuinely scary, in that you don't know whether the feature actually will vanish from the next major release of your implementation, never to return. Not really the case here.

Comment: @Steve: Well… the next major releases of our implementations are either already here or coming soon, it's a question of whether to upgrade. True, a lot of code is still written against the old version of Python for example, but I think the freedom to upgrade is still important. Supposing that someone will want *some* feature from C++0x, they'll want to think about forward compatibility.

Comment: I'm just thinking in the context of the many answers on this site that include, "this would be easier if you upgraded."

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to distinguish between a string literal and a pointer, based on the fact that string literals have array type, not pointer type:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(char *msg)
{
    std::cout << "non-const char*\n";
}

void foo(const char *&msg) // & needed, else this is preferred to the
                           // template function for a string literal
{
    std::cout << "const char*\n";
}

template <int N>
void foo(const char (&msg)[N])
{
    std::cout << "const char array reference ["<< N << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    foo("bar"); // const char array reference [4]
}
```

But note that all of them (including your original function) can be "fooled" by passing something that isn't a string literal:

```
const char *soap = 0;
foo(soap);

char *b = 0;
foo(b);

const char a[4] = {};
foo(a);
```

There is no type in C++ which is unique to string literals. So, you can use the type to tell the difference between an array and a pointer, but not to tell the difference between a string literal and another array. RTTI is no use, because RTTI exists only for classes with at least one virtual member function. Anything else is implementation-dependent: there is no guarantee in the standard that string literals will occupy any particular region of memory, or that the same string literal used twice in a program (or even in a compilation unit) will have the same address. In terms of storage location, anything that an implementation can do with string literals, it is permitted also to do with my array `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `foo()` in theory could use a macro to determine if the argument was a literal or not.

```
#define foo(X) (*#X == '"'
                ? foo_string_literal(X)
                : foo_not_string_literal(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

And what happens if you call it as:

```
const char bob[] = "bar";
foo(bob);
```

It's probably using some sort of distinction like that to make the determination.

EDIT: If there's only one function declaration in the header I can't conceive of any portable way the library could make that distinction.